# Passing tokens to a function in java

Tags: java, string, function, stringtokenizer

I have a text file named test5 which have 4 words. I need to pass these four words to both functions contVal and contVal2. When i execute the below code the first and third word goes to function contVal and second and forth word goes to contVal2. Is there any way i can pass all four words to both functions?

```
                String a = "D:/test5.txt" ;
                String abc = readFile(a);
                StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(abc);
                float cv1 = 1;
                float cv4 =1;
                while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
                {
                    float cv0 = contVal(a1,st.nextToken());
                    cv1 = cv0*cv1;
                    float cv3 = contVal2(a1,st.nextToken());
                    cv4=cv3*cv4;

                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each call to `st.nextToken()` consumes another token. Therefore each method gets just half of the tokens.

Store each token in a variable before passing it to the methods :

```
            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) 
            {
                String token = st.nextToken();
                float cv0 = contVal(a1,token);
                cv1 = cv0*cv1;
                float cv3 = contVal2(a1,token);
                cv4=cv3*cv4;
            }
```